# Safety for Cats: fly-screen?

Tags: cats, safety

I hope I am in the right place...

I am considering getting two cats, and am planning what changes by apartment would need for them.
I am living on the third floor, and in summer, while home, my windows are basically open all the time. I have a flyscreen velcroed against the window to keep bugs out.

I am absolutely sure this will NOT hold a cat if it pushes against it... and the drop BEHIND it it really high. I would actually feel better about a cat if there was no flyscreen at all, because the cat would not be tempted to push or jump against something that looks kind of climbable.

Does anyone have any experience if the flyscreen on a window like that would be a problem? Or should I find another bug-protection... or can a cat-protection be added?

The windows open to the inside, awesome for cleaning, but it mean I'd have a hard time blocking it.

Comment: You can get plastic netting that is hard for cats to claw through. Put this in a wooden frame and secure it to the window area to allow air in and keep the cat in too.

Comment: @Oldcat please don't use comments to answer the question, comments are for clarification. Please see [this meta discussion](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1870/should-we-start-flagging-comments-that-are-acting-as-answers) for further information

Answer (score 3):

Let me start by saying that having the window unscreened would actually be way more unsafe than having it screened. Cats won't necessarily not fall out of a high window just because they can see the danger. They may jump or fall regardless.

I think the real solution here is replacing the screen with something more sturdy, or securing the one you have better than velcro.

You can read more about the danger of cats and high open windows here: http://www.aspca.org/pet-care/cat-care/high-rise-syndrome